# OrientDB: export/import throws exception: "Invalid format. Found unsupported tag 'brokenRids'"

Tags: orientdb

Trying to use [OrientDB's export/import functionality](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Console-Command-Export.html), but I keep getting errors, both from command line client and by using the JavaAPI

Creating a database with minimal content, then calling

```
export database /tmp/db.export -excludeAll -includeClass="asdf"
```

then importing with

```
import database /tmp/db.export.gz
```

yields the error message `Invalid format. Found unsupported tag 'brokenRids'`. Here is the full console session to reproduce:

```
OrientDB console v.2.2.30 (build 43d850df23c0fd1edca7279761c2238fdc6cc576, branch 2.2.x) https://www.orientdb.com
Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
orientdb> create database plocal:/var/tmp/databases/test_export_import

Creating database [plocal:/var/tmp/databases/test_export_import] using the storage type [plocal]...Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Auto configuration of disk cache size.
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: 2095874048 B/1998 MB/1 GB of physical memory were detected on machine
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Soft memory limit for this process is set to -1 B/-1 MB/-1 GB
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Hard memory limit for this process is set to -1 B/-1 MB/-1 GB
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Path to 'memory' cgroup is '/docker/f88c313794174ac8b8d7ad7d9b5fe396aea8033a1588e7eb6a3f903773081b81'
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Mounting path for memory cgroup controller is '/sys/fs/memory'
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Can not find '/sys/fs/memory/docker/f88c313794174ac8b8d7ad7d9b5fe396aea8033a1588e7eb6a3f903773081b81' path for memory cgroup, it is supposed that process is running in container, will try to read root '/sys/fs/memory' memory cgroup data
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Can not read memory soft limit for cgroup '/sys/fs/memory'
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Can not read memory hard limit for cgroup '/sys/fs/memory'
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Detected memory limit for current process is 2095874048 B/1998 MB/1 GB
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=444MB (heap=444MB direct=444MB os=1,998MB)
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Lowering disk cache size from 444MB to 442MB.
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Lowering memory chunk size from 465,567,744B to 463,470,592B.
Dec 04, 2017 8:57:36 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: $ANSI{green {db=test_export_import}} Storage 'plocal:/var/tmp/databases/test_export_import' is created under OrientDB distribution : 2.2.30 (build 43d850df23c0fd1edca7279761c2238fdc6cc576, branch 2.2.x)

Database created successfully.

Current database is: plocal:/var/tmp/databases/test_export_import
orientdb {db=test_export_import}> create class asdf

Class created successfully. Total classes in database now: 11.

orientdb {db=test_export_import}> insert into asdf content {"one": "two", "three": "four"}

Inserted record 'asdf#17:0{one:two,three:four} v1' in 0.009000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=test_export_import}> select from asdf

+----+-----+------+------+------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|one   |three |
+----+-----+------+------+------+
|0   |#17:0|asdf  |two   |four  |
+----+-----+------+------+------+

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.005 sec(s).
orientdb {db=test_export_import}> export database /tmp/test_export_import.export -excludeAll -includeClass="asdf"
Exporting current database to: database /tmp/test_export_import.export -excludeAll -includeClass="asdf" in GZipped JSON format ...

Started export of database 'test_export_import' to /tmp/test_export_import.export.gz...
Exporting records...
- Cluster 'internal' (id=0)...OK (records=0/3)
- Cluster 'index' (id=1)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'manindex' (id=2)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'default' (id=3)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'orole' (id=4)...OK (records=0/3)
- Cluster 'ouser' (id=5)...OK (records=0/3)
- Cluster 'ofunction' (id=6)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'osequence' (id=7)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'oschedule' (id=8)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'v' (id=9)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'v_1' (id=10)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'v_2' (id=11)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'v_3' (id=12)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'e' (id=13)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'e_1' (id=14)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'e_2' (id=15)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'e_3' (id=16)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'asdf' (id=17)...OK (records=1/1)
- Cluster 'asdf_1' (id=18)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'asdf_2' (id=19)...OK (records=0/0)
- Cluster 'asdf_3' (id=20)...OK (records=0/0)

Done. Exported 1 of total 10 records. 0 records were detected as broken


Database export completed in 14ms
orientdb {db=test_export_import}> delete from asdf

Delete record(s) '1' in 0.004000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=test_export_import}> import database /tmp/test_export_import.export.gz

Importing database database /tmp/test_export_import.export.gz...
Started import of database 'plocal:/var/tmp/databases/test_export_import' from /tmp/test_export_import.export.gz...
Non merge mode (-merge=false): removing all default non security classes
- Class E was removed.
- Class V was removed.
- Class OTriggered was removed.
- Class ORestricted was removed.
- Class OSchedule was removed.
- Class asdf was removed.
- Class OSequence was removed.
- Class OFunction was removed.
Removed 8 classes.

Importing records...

Started migration of links (-migrateLinks=true). Links are going to be updated according to new RIDs:
- Cluster asdf_3... Completed migration of 0 records in current cluster
- Cluster ouser... Completed migration of 3 records in current cluster
- Cluster asdf_2... Completed migration of 0 records in current cluster
- Cluster asdf_1... Completed migration of 0 records in current cluster
- Cluster default... Completed migration of 0 records in current cluster
- Cluster orole... Completed migration of 3 records in current cluster
- Cluster asdf... Completed migration of 1 records in current cluster
Total links updated: 7

Done. Imported 1 records in 0.05 secs
Error on database import happened just before line 0, column 116
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImportException: Invalid format. Found unsupported tag 'brokenRids'
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport.importDatabase(ODatabaseImport.java:189)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.console.OConsoleDatabaseApp.importDatabase(OConsoleDatabaseApp.java:2188)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.orientechnologies.common.console.OConsoleApplication.execute(OConsoleApplication.java:405)
at com.orientechnologies.common.console.OConsoleApplication.executeCommands(OConsoleApplication.java:260)
at com.orientechnologies.common.console.OConsoleApplication.run(OConsoleApplication.java:131)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.console.OConsoleDatabaseApp.main(OConsoleDatabaseApp.java:145)

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseExportException: Error on importing database 'test_export_import' from file: /tmp/test_export_import.export.gz

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImportException: Invalid format. Found unsupported tag 'brokenRids'
```

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT: the exported data looks like this:

```
gunzip -c /tmp/test_export_import.export.gz
{"records":[{"@type":"d","@rid":"#17:0","@version":1,"@class":"asdf","one":"two","three":"four"}],"brokenRids":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

it means that you try to import data which were exported by an older version of ODB. We do not support compatibility from the future to the past versions, but support compatibility in opposite way, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrey. I don't understand how that can be, though. As can be seen from the console session above, I create the database, create a class, insert som data, export, delete data, then import, all in the same console session, at the same server, v2.2.30:

Comment: Could you send me your export data?

Comment: Exported data added, see above edit. As you can see, it contains the offending tag `brokenRids`.

Comment: sorry to bother you about this, but do you consider this a bug or not? Looking at `ODatabaseExport` v2.2.30, it looks like the tag `brokenRids` is in fact written to the exported data, while the class `ODatabaseImport` of the same version doesn't seem not handle the same tag. Any help much appreciated, we are using the system in production.